# PHP $_SESSION data not saving from page to page

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm beating my head against the wall right now. I've been fiddling with this for hours, and I can't seem to figure it out.

My sessions data isn't saving when I navigate from one page to another. I've set this up in WAMP, BTW.

The cookies are being saved, and the sessions data only works when I reset it at the beginning of EVERY script. I'm not quite sure what to do here. It's probably something ridiculously stupid, but any input is greatly appreciated.

my login script:

```
<?php 


include('../partials/_header.php');
include('includes/connectvars.php');


if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { //logged in?

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {       // form submitted?

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) { /* Check to make sure post isn't empty in case of JS override/disable */

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
        $password = sha1(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password'])));
        /* query DB */
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ("There was an error with your mySQL query:" . mysqli_error($dbc));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) { /* Check that matching row exists in users for login */

                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id']; // set the session info
                $_SESSION['type'] = $row['type'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['f_name'];

                setcookie('id', $row['id'], time()+ (60*60*24*30));
                setcookie('type', $row['type'], time()+ (60*60*24*30));
                setcookie('name', $row['f_name'], time()+ (60*60*24*30));
                $home_url = '/'; //redirect not working with $_SERVER variable in WAMP. keep an eye for the future
                header('Location: '.$home_url);
                mysqli_close($dbc);

        } else { /* if no match in database ask to resubmit login info or register */?> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                  $("#login_form").validate();
                                 });
                        </script>
                        <div class="span-24 colborder">
                            <form id="login_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                                <label class="error">Your email and/or password are incorrect. </label><br />
                                <label class="error">If you haven't already signed up, feel free to <a href="user_registration.php" > register</a> </label><br /> 
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="email required" placeholder="example@example.com"/> <br />
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" value="" /> <br />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
                            </form>
                        </div>

    <?php


        }/* end conditional to check $rows array for username pw match */
    } /* end conditional to check that form isn't blank */ 
    else { /* If form is blank ask to resubmit or register */?> 
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                  $("#login_form").validate();
                                 });
                        </script>
        <div class="span-24 colborder">
            <form id="login_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                <label class="error">You must enter your email and password if you wish to continue.</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="email required" placeholder="example@example.com"/> <br />
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" value="" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
            </form>
        </div>

    <?php

    } // end else to resubmit in case of blank form
    } /* end check if form has been submitted */ else{ /* prompt for login if page visited but login form not submitted */ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                  $("#login_form").validate();
                                 });
                        </script>
        <div class="span-24 colborder">
            <form id="login_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                <label class="error">You must be logged in to do that!.</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="email required" placeholder="example@example.com"/> <br />
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" value="" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
            </form>
        </div>  

                                                                    <?php

                                                                    }

    } /* end check if cookie isset */ else { //redirect if cookies & session is already set
                                                    $home_url = '/'; 
                                                    header('Location: '.$home_url);
                                                        }


?>


<?php include('partials/_footer.php'); ?>
```

this is my header (which includes the set session variable if cookie isset)

```
<?php //set session if isset cookie but not session
                session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

        if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['name']) && isset($_COOKIE['type'])) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $_COOKIE['name'];
                $_SESSION['type'] = $_COOKIE['type'];
            }       
    }   //end if !isset session verify


?>
```

and an example of the menu output depending on their session id:

```
            <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['type']) && $_SESSION['type'] == "rnr") { //start special runner menu options
    ?> 
            <ul class="main_menu">
            <li id="how_it_works" class="main_menu"><a class="main_menu" href="/user/bid_task.php">Bid on a task</a></li>
            <li id="our_runners" class="main_menu"><a class="main_menu" href="/our_runners.php">Our Runners</a></li>
            <li id="login" class="main_menu"><a class="main_menu" href="/user/my_account.php">My account</a></li>
            <li id="register" class="main_menu"><a class="main_menu" href="/user/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>       


    <?php } /* end runner menu */ ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So anyone can specify `name = admin` in their cookie and become an admin?

Comment: No. Name is simply their first name.

Comment: ok. how about specifying arbitrary id? What if I specify `id = 1` in my cookie?

Comment: Yeah... I'm sure it's pretty obvious I'm just a beginner. Would I have to do something with the cookie's http settings to prevent that?

Comment: just don't store it in cookies

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

If i want to store it in sessions, they keep getting deleted anyway. You have any input?

Answer (score 0):

The header file is included before the setcookie function is called in your login script. Based on what I see, the cookie is not set at the time you do this condition check:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['name']) && isset($_COOKIE['type']))
```

And because of that it never get inside the condition statement and following lines do not get executed in the header file:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $_COOKIE['name'];
$_SESSION['type'] = $_COOKIE['type'];
```

Comment: I removed the header file include and just ran the login script and it still didnt work.

The sessions

Comment: hmm...well removing it wont help, you need to set the session somewhere..the problem is that you are setting the session from the cookie, and you are not setting the cookie before the session..so it will not work..

Comment: Please ignore my earlier, comment I read the code incorrectly *sheepish grin*

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience.

I thought I was setting the session in the login script. Shouldnt that set it first? and I don't think I wrote anything that would erase the session data.

I'm sorry if my questions seem stupid.

Comment: are you including your header file at the top of each page? Also what did you mean by The cookies are being saved, and the sessions data only works when I reset it at the beginning of EVERY script

Comment: My page works perfectly until I turn off cookies in my browser. 

I can login and navigate normally.

By resetting the sessions data at the beginning of each script, i mean  the function to set the $_SESSION data from $_COOKIE['id'] that i put in the top of the header. If i try and echo $_SESSION['id']; after navigating to a page that doesn't have that function, nothing works i get an undefined index error

Comment: That page will be required in all pages where you use session. once session is set, you can only access it in pages where session_start() is called. And in your case it is called in header.php. So either you have to include that page in all other pages where you are accessing session, or you have to add the line session_start() to such pages explicitly at the top before accessing any session variable.

Comment: even with the session_start(); function, I can't access the sessions variables once i navigate away from a page where I've explicitly copied the value of $_COOKIE['id'] to $_SESSION['id'].